# Uncaught Error: Module name "twilio" has not been loaded yet

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, twilio, browserify

## Problem

I'm receiving an error in the terminal related to the `require` method when I'm looking to send a pre-done SMS message through Twilio. I've read other similar StackOverflow questions and I've tried to use include the CDN for RequireJS in my scripts section my `index.html`, alternatively npm installing Browserify, but I'm not sure why I'm still getting the error.

## Error

`Uncaught Error: Module name "twilio" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

### scripts.js

```
// Twilio Credentials
var accountSid = 'AC7*********';
var authToken = '6b6*********';

// Require the Twilio module and create a REST client
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.create({
    to: "+16479933461",
    from: "+12044002143",
    body: "There is a new highest bidder. Visit {{websiteUrl}} to place another bid. All proceeds from the silent auction will go to the Samaritian House.",
    mediaUrl: "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg",
}, function(err, message) {
    console.log(message.sid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

According to the [RequireJS errors page](http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded), when using RequireJS like this, you should use the asynchronous loading method, like this:

```
// Twilio Credentials
var accountSid = 'AC7*********';
var authToken = '6b6*********';

// Require the Twilio module and create a REST client
require(['twilio'], function(twilio){
  var client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages.create({
      to: "+16479933461",
      from: "+12044002143",
      body: "There is a new highest bidder. Visit {{websiteUrl}} to place another bid. All proceeds from the silent auction will go to the Samaritian House.",
      mediaUrl: "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg",
  }, function(err, message) {
      console.log(message.sid);
  });
});
```

If this is in the terminal, can I ask why you are using RequireJS though? Node.js has `require` built in and synchronous.

I'm wondering if you are trying to use the Twilio module in the front end? If so, you shouldn't as you expose your account credentials which could be used to abuse your account. It's better and safer to perform Twilio API requests on a  server. That's what the Node.js module is for.

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around Node, similarly phrased, previously asked questions on Stack pointed towards RequireJS as a possible solution. My intention is to be able to have an app for a silent auction that tell people by SMS that someone has outbid them using Twilio. I'm wondering now that you mention security, where should I store my credentials instead?

Comment: They should be stored on the server, is what you are doing right now on the server or for the front end?

Comment: Right now, the entire app is built on the front-end. So I'm curious what might be my best option?

Comment: You really don't want to expose your credentials online. What you want to do is build a back end service that handles sending the SMS messages which you can just call with an Ajax method in the front end. There's a good bunch of tutorials on how to do this on the Twilio site. This one might be a good start: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/lead-alerts/node/express

Comment: Is there any way to approach this without having to build a back-end?